# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se me imprima en pantalla todo lo que un usuario introdujo en distintas variables en Python?

Tags: python, print

En la opción numero 1 después de que el usuario escriba toda la información que se le solicita quiero que al final en donde esta la variable ***todo = ("Todas las tareas introducidas son: ")*** me arroje lo que hay dentro de las variables **nom_tar, fech_enc y fech_ent**
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
print("********************")
print("* Gestor de tareas *")
print("******************** \n")

nombre = "Hola "
nombre += input("Escribe tu nombre: ")
bienvenida = print(nombre, ", bienvenido al gestor de tareas!! \n")

pregunta = print(nombre, ", ¿que desea hacer?:")

seleccionar = int(input("""1. Ingresar tareas.
2. Ver las tareas realizadas.
3. Ver las tareas pendientes. \n
Elija una opcion: """))

if seleccionar == 1:
    print("Haz elegido 'Ingresar tareas' \n")
    num_tareas = int(input("¿Cuantas tareas desea agregar?: "))
    contador = 0
    while contador < num_tareas:
        nom_tar = input("Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: ")
        fech_enc = input('Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": ')
        fech_ent = input('Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": ')
        contador += 1

        todo= print("Todas las tareas introducidas son: ")


elif seleccionar == 2:
    print("Haz elegido 'Ver las tareas realizadas' \n")



elif seleccionar == 3:
    print("Haz elegido 'Ver las tareas pendientes' \n")

else:
    print("Esa opcion no existe. Vuelva a intentarlo.")
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la dificultad?

Comment: Es que cuando el ciclo se repite pues las tareas son mas y al momento de quererlas imprimir en pantalla solo se imprime la ultima que se ingreso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución "pitonica":

```
num_tareas = int(input("¿Cuantas tareas desea agregar?: "))
tareas = []
while len(tareas) < num_tareas:
    nom_tar = input("Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: ")
    fech_enc = input('Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": ')
    fech_ent = input('Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": ')
    tareas.append((nom_tar, fech_enc, fech_ent))

for nom_tar, fech_enc, fech_ent in tareas:
    print(nom_tar, fech_enc, fech_ent)
```

Si tienes que almacenar un número de cosas, lo usual es guardarlas en una lista, que en este caso llamaremos `tareas`.

La lista está inicialmente vacía y vamos agregando las tareas una a una, en forma de una tupla de 3 elementos: nombre, fecha inicio, fecha de entrega. La tupla se forma al encerrar los tres valores entre paréntesis.

No necesitamos llevar un contador por separado para saber cuantas tareas hemos ingresado, pues este valor es igual al largo de la lista.

Una vez terminado el ciclo `for`, podemos imprimir la lista. Fijate que la impresión debe estar fuera del ciclo; si no, se imprimira cada vez que se agregue una nueva tarea.

Para recorrer la lista usamos el siguiente `for`, que puede parecer un poco raro:

```
for nom_tar, fech_enc, fech_ent in tareas:
```

En este `for` suceden dos cosas: 1) Primero se extrae una tupla, que se ve como `("tarea1", "22/01/01", "22/01/02")` e inmediatamente la desempaquetamos, asignando cada cada a una variable distinta. Asi que más claro que estar usando `tupla[0], tupla[1], tupla[2]`.

#### Demo

```
¿Cuantas tareas desea agregar?: 5
Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: tarea1
Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": 2022/01/01
Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": 2022/01/02
Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: tarea2
Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/03
Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/04
Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: tarea3
Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/05
Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/06
Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: tarea4
Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/07
Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/08
Escriba el nombre de esta tarea: tarea5
Fecha en que se encargo "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/09
Fecha en que se entrega "aaa/mm/dd": 22/01/10
tarea1 2022/01/01 2022/01/02
tarea2 22/01/03 22/01/04
tarea3 22/01/05 22/01/06
tarea4 22/01/07 22/01/08
tarea5 22/01/09 22/01/10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: He estado tratando de intentarlo desde hace 30 minutos y no se me había ocurrido usar un for para imprimir, Gran respuesta.

Comment: @Candid Moe muchas gracias. Esto resolvió mi problema. GRACIAS!!!